# How to modify the tensor data dimension in pytorch, thanks

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I want to transform the tensor data to numpy data and save it through Opencv, But the opencv require the data dimension must like such style [1, something, something, something], but my tensor data is a blend one, it'e size like [30, something, something, something],how can I modify the data dimension in pytorch.

PS, is there any function in pytorch can save data as a binary picture? I use "save_image" command to save my tensor data to a picture with all figure is 1 or 0, but the picture show is still a gray style. Maybe there is any other ways to save tensor data as a binary picture, please tell me.

```
               def save_image_tensor2cv2(input_tensor, filename):
                   assert (len(input_tensor.shape) == 4) and input_tensor.shape[0] == 1)
                   input_tensor = input_tensor.clone().detach()
                   input_tensor = input_tensor.to(torch.device('cpu'))
                   input_tensor = input_tensor.squeeze()
                   input_tensor = input_tensor.mul_(255).add_(0.5).clamp_(0, 255).permute(1, 2, 0).type(torch.uint8).numpy()
                   cv2.imwrite(filename, input_tensor)
```

Comment: These seem like the kind of questions than can be answered by reading the documentation. Have you done so? In any case, I think this is far too vague.

Comment: I just want save my tensor data to picture by opencv, the opencv require the data shape like [1,....,...,...] the first figure is 1 and have 4 dimension, but my data shape is [30,...,...,...] the first figure is 30 ,how can I modify the figure from 30 to 1?

Comment: Just reshape it or slice it, no? Mind you that may technically work, but it’s probably not strictly correct. If you need a real in-depth answer to this, it’s going to take far more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
batch = next(iter(dataloader_test))

batch.shape
torch.Size([4, 3, 160, 160])

np.transpose(batch.numpy(), (0,2,3,1)).shape
(4, 160, 160, 3)

image = np.transpose(batch.numpy(), (0,2,3,1))

cv2.imwrite("image.png", image[0])
```

You might have to unNormalize the data before saving it though.

Comment: thanks, and if my channel is 1 instead 3 in the data, is that ok?

Comment: @mapex yes that is fine

Comment: I try the codes you paste, it can work, but the result is not what I want to get, my tensor data is get from "imgs = torch.cat((x.cpu(), x_mask.cpu(), completed.cpu()), dim=0)", it's shape is [30, 1, 320,320], it should be a blend picture with 30 smaller picture. with your code I just get a whole black picture, I don't totally understand your code such as image[0]

Comment: @mapex oh you want a grid of all the pictures?